# Having both JUnit and Cucumber tests in a single Android project

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, cucumber

I am looking to introduce Cucumber tests into my Android application.  In order to do that, I need a custom test instrumentation runner that makes use of `CucumberInstrumentationCore` as described [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/android).

However I already have Espresso tests that are driven by JUnit, and I therefore already have a custom test instrumentation runner that uses `AndroidJUnitTestRunner`.

It seems to me that a custom implementation cannot use both simultaneously, because the `onStart()` methods of each call `finish()` on the tested activity.

It seems that my options are:

- Copy the source code of both `CucumberInstrumentationCore` and `AndroidJUnitTestRunner` and produce a new, combined test runner that performs the necessary parts of both

Or...

- Have the JUnit tests in the `androidTest` folder, and create a new instrumentation test folder alongside `androidTest` which contains only the Cucumber tests.  Is this even possible?

How can I proceed, and have I missed a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up producing a combined `instrumentationTestRunner` which seems to work OK:

https://gist.github.com/dhoskins/98afa6976c87cb20328d42065c7292ee